# Azure DevOps Odata Group by child property is not working

Tags: odata, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am using the Azure DevOps Odata endpoints to retrieve data from my projects.

Now I face the problem that I am not able to group by the result based on a sub property of a workitem.
The following ODATA query returns me an error message:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/<organisation>/<project>/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems?
$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Activity'&
$select=AssignedTo/UserName,TotalCount&
$apply=groupby((AssignedTo/UserName, WorkItemType),aggregate($count as TotalCount))&
$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName)
```

> VS403483: The query specified in the URI is not valid: VS403522: The property 'AssignedTo' is not available on the specified Project(s). Please remove 'AssignedTo' from your query and try again..","innererror":{"message":"VS403522: The property 'AssignedTo' is not available on the specified Project(s). Please remove 'AssignedTo' from your query and try again.

```
{
    "State": "Closed",
    "AssignedTo": {
        "UserName": "User 2"
    }
},
{
    "State": "New",
    "AssignedTo": {
        "UserName": "User 1"
    }
}
```

When I try to do the same with a normal property, everything works fine:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/<organisation>/<project>/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems?
$filter=WorkItemType eq 'Activity'&
$select=State,TotalCount&
$apply=groupby((State, WorkItemType),aggregate($count as TotalCount))
```

Comment: @R Pelzer, Would you please share the latest information about this issue? Could you get helpful suggestion from Frank's answer? Any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I added a comment on the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query url.

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_odata/v2.0/WorkItems?
$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Bug')/groupby((AssignedTo/UserName, WorkItemType),aggregate($count as TotalCount))
&select=AssignedTo/UserName,TotalCount
```

And then you will get the result as below.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_odata/v2.0/$metadata#WorkItems(AssignedTo(UserName),WorkItemType,TotalCount)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": null,
            "WorkItemType": "Bug",
            "TotalCount": 3,
            "AssignedTo": {
                "@odata.id": null,
                "UserName": "{username1}"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": null,
            "WorkItemType": "Bug",
            "TotalCount": 4,
            "AssignedTo": {
                "@odata.id": null,
                "UserName": "{username2}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was hoping that I could also include the UserName in the select, so I had all the needed data in 1 query. Now I have to do a second query to get the username

Comment: @RPelzer, I have update my answer, you can check it.